# Bootstrap Carousel Indicators on different lines

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

A slight problem, if I insert a line break in the middle of my indicators like so:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
    <br />
    <li data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
</ol>
```

The 1-to-1 correspondence is messed up at the break! The line break acts as an almost invisible indicator?!

Comment: That's because the `ol` tag may contain **only** `li` elements. [(source)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ol.html)

Comment: But <br /> is not an element?

Comment: To be aligned horizontally as indicators, `li` items likely are displayed as `inline-block`s, so they flow with text. When you insert a line break, there's whitespace before (which will likely shift top line to the left) and after it (which will shift bottom line right). Hence they got misaligned. Just don't leave spaces and new lines around line break, and it should be ok.

Comment: No when I say misaligned, I mean the wrong image is being indicated.

Comment: Of course it is. Just like an ordinary div, img or meta.

Comment: So how Do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

What Alex is saying to do is this:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel"></li><br /><li data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
</ol>
```

Don't leave spaces between the line break. Also, you don't need to use the / in the line break anymore. That's old school.

Comment: I've done that but clicking the 7th thumbnail doesn't light up the indicator and clicking the 8th lights up the 7th indicator, 9 lights up 8 and so on?! Also, nothing wrong with a bit of old school!

Comment: What if you try giving a class to the 7th indicator like "return" and then in your css, return:before { content: '\A'; } ?

Comment: It was a worth a try. Could you make a js.fiddle so I can experiment some?